# To print the contents present in SOAP header in the console

Tags: jboss, esb, soapheader, soaphttpclientprotocol

I want to print the contents present in the soap-header in my jboss-esb console but I'm not able to do so.

I'm only able to print the body of the soap content but not the contents present in the header part.

Can any one help me to print the contents present in the soupui header in my jboss console?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? I am not a JBoss person but have you tried http://docs.jboss.org/jbossesb/docs/4.10/manuals/html/Programmers_Guide/index.html#d0e1480?

Comment: possible duplicate of [To display the contents present in soap header in JBoss esb console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850288/to-display-the-contents-present-in-soap-header-in-jboss-esb-console)